# Firefox Horizontal List Scrolling CSS

Tags: css, firefox, scroll

I have a list that is set to display horizontally instead of vertically. It's also set to full screen height (not sure if that would make any difference). The list displays correctly in Chrome and Safari, but it only displays the first item in Firefox. Sometimes if I refresh, it will display all the items, but only in a vertical format. I've tried several fixes and none seem to work. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="project">

<li class="item">
<div class="overlay">
<section class="img-info">
  <h1>Ro, 2012</h1>

</section>
</div>
<img src="01.jpg" />
</li>

<li class="item">
<div class="overlay">
<section class="img-info">
  <h1>Jonathan, 2012</h1>

</section>
</div>
<img src="02.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
article.projects {
    height:100%;
    float:none;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

article.projects ul.project {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding-left:72px;
}

article.projects ul.project li.item {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    min-width:300px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:1px;
}
```

The site is live here - http://jennaegarrett.com/

The site is responsive, so if you go into the code the relevant css will be at the bottom of the file.

Comment: does it really need t be a list?

Comment: Not necessarily, but would that even make any difference if the default li styles have been removed?

Comment: yes, lis arent containers,even if you reset the styling, use divs instead

Comment: also note, that inline-block as well as float shrink wraps, so you probably should give ul.project some width too

Comment: Tried changing both and still no dice. I thought about giving the wrap some width, but the problem is I want the width to be related to the number of items in the project... basically no extra white space at the end of the list.

Comment: Both my FF and Chrome are showing funky @ 1300x380 viewport size...content omitted. From that size shrinking to mobile, it seems to click into place (chrome); however, there is still a 70ish px margin running down the left side of the images. From that point, opening to tablet frames up the first photo nicely, but the remaining content is omitted again (still in chrome). You may want to relook at your @media queries - start at mobile, and work up ensuring each "stage" is working correctly before moving on.

Comment: BTW - I like the use of the UL, but I think you could simplify your code by targeting elements, and avoiding all the class declarations `<ul id="projects">` `#projects li {...} #projects h1 {...}` (much much easier to read after 6months on the shelf.

Comment: article.projects has overflow scroll yet no width set, doesnt seem right, if you only want to enclose floats, use inline-block, clear after